# What does a function with this ~ mean? (e.g. function=f(~, x, y))

Tags: matlab, function, function-handle, tilde

I am doing another coursera assignemnt, this time with aerial robotics. I have to program a pd controller using the matlab `ode45` (ordinary diff. equation). And the file that has to contain this code gets called as follows:

```
pd_controller(~, s, s_des, params)
```

I searched around but couldn't find anthing that explain this to me and how it works.

In the main program the function is called with a time variable which I would need for my ODE:

```
controlhandle(t, s, s_des, params)
```

Where this controlhandle is the functionhandler for pd_controller.

So, what does this mean? And can I access whatever is behind `~`?

Besides: 
I found one example, but the other around. A function, let's call it `function = f(a,b)` was called with `f(~, b)` where `a` and `b` has been declared inside the function.

Comment: Matlab's help works for operators as well: `help ~`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol is called a tilde, and it signifies that you are ignoring that input argument.

See the documentation here: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-inputs.html

In your case, the function `controlhandle` will not be passed a `t` variable, and probably has (should have) some check for this and perhaps a default `t` if none is given.

---

This works the same with output arguments, for example if you want the *index* of a max in an array, but not the max itself, you would use

```
a = [pi, 3.6, 1];
[~, idx] = max(a); % idx = 2, we don't know what the max value is
```

Answer (score 4):

It means you don't need pass this parameter in this function call. Also, you can use it in the output of some functions too. For example:

```
A = [1 4 2 2 41];
[~, B] = sort(A);
```

this means you don't need the second output, and you can ignore that.

In your case, when no value sent for the first parameter `t`, probably the function acts on a default value for `t` in his computation.

Also, you can find more about that in [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-inputs.html). 
I should have mentioned that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38515691/3768871) exists as an answer, but it might be here instead.